# MySQL query to get sum of difference between Start date and End date

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has the following data:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Date_from | Date_to   |
+-----------+-----------+
| 20-NOV-19 | 22-NOV-19 |
+-----------+-----------+
| 10-NOV-19 | 21-NOV-19 |
+-----------+-----------+
| 14-NOV-19 | 26-NOV-19 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I need a query to find the sum of the difference between `date_from` and `date_to`.

Example:

- The difference between 20-Nov-19 and 22-Nov-19 is 2 days
- The difference between 10-Nov-19 and 21-Nov-19 is 11 days but the query has to consider it as 9 days because days 20-Nov, 21-Nov are already considered in the first row.
- The difference between 14-Nov-19 and 26-Nov-19 is 12 days but the query has to consider it as 4 days because days 14-Nov to 22-Nov are already considered in the above rows.

The query result should be

> 15 days (2+9+4)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the _types_ of your two date columns?  Are they date columns, text, or something else?

Comment: They are date columns

Comment: Is it correct to assume that an additional entry of dates from 10-MAR-19 to 12-MAR-19 would just add two days to the intended sum?

Comment: Somethink like:
`datediff(max(Date_to),min(Date_from))-1` can it be ok?

Comment: I think you have to first sorting your days first. lowest date to highest date. Then calculate to days difference

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to get total. 
Please change Table_name with your actual table name

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,Date_from,Date_to)) as total FROM Table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I used window functions in a sub-query to calculate the difference between date_from and date_to and then subtracting any overlapping days

```
SELECT SUM(days) FROM
    (SELECT CASE WHEN LEAD(date_from) OVER w  < date_to THEN DATEDIFF(date_to, date_from) + DATEDIFF(LEAD(date_from) OVER w, date_to)
          ELSE DATEDIFF(date_to, date_from)
          END AS days
          FROM test
          WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY date_to)) as d
```

Note though that this produces the result 16 days, not 15 as in the question, but then again so does

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2019-11-26', '2019-11-10')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CTE` to generate all the dates between the range and get the `distinct count()`.It will give you the total number of days as `17`. Since you want difference you have to subtract by 2(start date and end date)

```
WITH recursive Date_Ranges AS (
    select datefrom as Dt,dateto from mydates
   union all
   select dt + interval 1 day , dateto
   from Date_Ranges
   where dt < dateto)
select count(distinct(dt))-2 from Date_Ranges
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c07ebc1132a8543a2cf2907e841a6ba8)